# 123 reg changing mx record, while nameserver points elsewhere

Tags: dns, nameservers

I have a domain with 123-reg which i have pointed the domain name to UK fast name servers to host the site, however i wish the emails to be hosted with my previous provider still.

How would i change the MX Record to this domain if the name servers are with UKfast? All help guides on 123reg mention the name servers need to be 123-reg name servers. Is there a way to change the MX records without changing the A record or name servers?

**Below is the only guidance my provider has given me.**

After creating any of these services, you will be able to view your custom MX record in the DuoCircle control panel.  After sign-in, click on the "My Services" link then click the table row for the relevant service.  On that page look for "Your Custom MX" under the Service Settings heading and use the value provided to its right.  This custom MX record will be of the format a######.mx.mailhop.org or the record specified in your account.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "UK Fast" nameservers for your zone, you need to deal with this company (and not the registrar 123-reg) to add/modify the MX record in your zone.